# Calabash Android: Check if a button is present and enabled

Tags: android, automation, automated-tests, android-testing, calabash

I am new to Calabash and sadly, possess no programming experience, so I hope people shall be patient with me and offer explicit answers.

---

On the Login page, I am successfully able to check for the...

- **Email Address** field
- **Password** field

but I can't seem to test for the presence and enabled state of the...

- **Sign in** button
- **Hide button** (to hide or show the Password typed)
- **Password Help and Recovery** button

Using `query("*")`, I can obtain all the IDs but I'm stumped about the actual query commands with which to test.

This is my test thus far:

```
Feature: Sign In appearance
Scenario: Upon launch, all elements of the login page should appear correctly
    Then I see "Email Address"
    Then I see "Password"
    Then I see "button marked:'Sign In'"
```

Which yields the following results:

```
Then I see "button marked:'Sign In'"                              # calabash-android-0.4.20/lib/calabash-android/steps/assert_steps.rb:5
  Action 'assert_text' unsuccessful: Text'button marked:'Sign In'' was not found (RuntimeError)
  features/Login_appearance.feature:6:in `Then I see "button marked:'Sign In'"'
Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/Login_appearance.feature:3
```

---

How shall I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to use the predefined steps create a custom step and use the Ruby api's `query` and `wait_for_elements_exist` methods.

Take a look at this post first to learn more about the query language:
http://krazyrobot.com/2014/04/calabash-using-query/

Then find the elements with `query` possibly by id, eg.:

- query("* id:'email_field'")
- query("* id:'pwd_field'")

Create a custom step in your step definition and use the `wait_for_elements_exist` method to verify the elements:

```
Then /^all the elements are present on the login screen$/ do
    wait_for_elements_exist(["* id:'email_field'", "* id:'pwd_field'"])
end
```

Comment: Yes, I can successfully wait for those elements. Calabash also confirms the button exists but how do I check that the button is enabled?

Comment: By that, I mean, how do I check whether the button is tappable, that it is listening to input?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried replacing

```
Then I see "button marked:'Sign In'"
```

with

```
Then I see "Sign In"
```

?

Comment: Calabash does not see the text labels of the buttons in our app. So, eventually, when my knowledge of Calabash advanced enough, I used the view_id of the button, which worked.